# Does ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback work even when app is termintated

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I am using ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback to register if there are any changes being made to the AddressBook database. I have it working fine for me and am able to receive the notifications, but they work only when the app is running.

Once the app is killed (terminated), and then restarted, it does not recognize the changes during that time between kill and restart.

Is there a way to detect those changes or was this designed to work this way?

Sample code that I am using -

in viewDidLoad -

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook,addressBookChanged,(__bridge void *)(self));
```

And the callback

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef reference, CFDictionaryRef dictionary, void *context) {
NSLog(@"There was a change in the addressbook");
```

Answer (score 1):

No, these alerts will only be received when your app is active.

Possibly the iOS7 support for background processing will allow for some sort of monitoring, but probably not using this callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to cook up some solutions for this issue right now and am thinking of using this callback and also storing the size of the address book elsewhere and on app launch, comparing their sizes to determine if a change has occurred. I'm assuming that most changes will likely cause a small difference in size one way or another. Between both of these I think an imperfect but passable solution could exist.

Comment: I did a strong brainstorming on this. And storing the size will not work. What if it is +1 and -1. The size change will be zero but there are changes to the contacts. The way I am handling this is using core data. Store all the synced/used contacts in the coredata model, each contact has an ID, and then you can compare that with what is in the ABAddressBook.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense - but can't you measure the actual size of the address book file, as opposed to just the number of contacts - something that is much more fine grain. Even though it would be theoretically imperfect it might for pretty much any conceivable situation, give you an accurate measure of change.

Comment: Again the underlying problem lies that you cant be sure about the size. Same number of bytes can be removed and written. Think of each contact as an entity, you need to be able to find difference for every field for every entity. And you can only do that if you have stored the previous version of the data somewhere to compare with.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. Thanks!